# What's a good way to install a linux distro, from already installed linux distribution?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, installation

I'd like to install a copy of Solus Budgie on my Windows laptop. However, I don't have any flash drives to install a live OS on, since I installed Solus Budgie on the only flash drive I had (and I'm currently asking this question from that install). As stated before, I'm running a regular copy of Solus Budgie on my flash drive. Is it possible to install Solus Budgie on my laptop's hard-drive, from the flash drive that's running the installed linux distro? If it's possible, what's a good way to do this? I couldn't find any useful information about this on the internet, and I hope this question makes it easier for others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can find many guide how to boot ISO by adding a GRUB custom entry. Most of them addresses Ubuntu which uses casper. I have to have a Solus iso. I used an modified entry for CentOS. It booted but `initrd-switch-root.service` failed, sending me to root shell. Anyway, UNetbootin can write iso to HDD. See [this](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes#hard-disk-install-mode). Make a partition, burn the ISO on that partition using Unetbootin (from Windows, but Linux may work as well). Boot from HDD as Live media and install.